# I am trying to run Kmeans clustering in spark , for which I am getting an exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

```
**Python Version = 2.6.6**

**numpy version = 1.3.0**  

**** The python file dokmeans.py is located in /home/cloudera****  






 Welcome to
          ____              __
         / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
        _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
       /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.3.0
          /_/

    Using Python version 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 22 2013 00:00:18)
    SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlCtx.
    >>> exec(open('dokmeans.py').read())
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        raise Exception("MLlib requires NumPy 1.4+")
    Exception: MLlib requires NumPy 1.4+
    >>> from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans,KMeansModel
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        raise Exception("MLlib requires NumPy 1.4+")
    Exception: MLlib requires NumPy 1.4+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error code says all. In order to use MLlib, you'll need to install numpy 1.4. You have 1.3 installed.

Comment: How do I install numpy 1.4?

Comment: I am finding this very confusing , can you please help me out installing numpy 1.4 in unix system.

Comment: Thanks , for the solution.

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug in the mllib code, which does not interpret the numpy version correctly. It interprets 1.10 as 1.1 and hence the check for the numpy version fails.

Please change the code in the below file
/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/**init**.py

from:

```
**if numpy.version.version < '1.4':**
raise Exception("MLlib requires NumPy 1.4+")
```

to:

```
ver = [int(x) for x in numpy.version.version.split('.')[:2]]
if ver < [1, 4]:
    raise Exception("MLlib requires NumPy 1.4+")
```